# Is there any way to install Entity Framework that I won't need to install it every MVC project I create in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, installation

I use Visual Studio 2017. 
Every time I create MVC project, I need to install Entity Framework every time. I want to install EF in such a way that I won't need to install it again.

Comment: And as far as I know, to create a custom MVC project template is a good way to achieve what you want. You can feel free to follow the link in Felipe's comment to do that...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by running the following command:
Tools->NuGet Packet Manager->Package Manager Console.
Install-Package EntityFramework

Comment: I have tried both with console and package solution.

Comment: Try using a custom template https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-create-a-custom-project-template-for-mvc-with-entity-framework/